# Assigning QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer default ramp colors?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, symbology, categorized-renderer

I have a plugin and I want to symbology a vector file with some default ramp colors but I see that in graduated symbology is not so easy as in graduated symbology.

Is it possible to assign a default ramp color to a vector file?

My code is very confusing because I tried so many examples but I couldn't get the result.

```
for code, (color, label) in attribute_sym.items():
    sym = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    sym.setColor(QColor(color))
    category = QgsRendererCategoryV2(code, sym, label)
    categories.append(category)

self.field = self.dockwidget.comboBox.currentText()
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2(self.field, categories)
layer.setRendererV2(renderer)           
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

This code works but I don't want to allways define the list with the colors, because I am trying to symbology several fields. Is it some way of using the default ramp colors?

Answer (score 2):

You may get access to the default ramp colors in this way:

```
defStyle = QgsStyleV2().defaultStyle()
defaultColorRampNames = defStyle.colorRampNames()
print defaultColorRampNames

# The print command returns this list:
# [u'Blues', u'BrBG', u'BuGn', u'BuPu', u'GnBu', u'Greens', u'Greys', u'Inferno', u'Magma', u'OrRd', u'Oranges', u'PRGn', u'PiYG', u'Plasma', u'PuBu', u'PuBuGn', u'PuOr', u'PuRd', u'Purples', u'RdBu', u'RdGy', u'RdPu', u'RdYlBu', u'RdYlGn', u'Reds', u'Spectral', u'Viridis', u'YlGn', u'YlGnBu', u'YlOrBr', u'YlOrRd']
```

Then, you may set the ramp by specifying the index of the ramp from the list printed in the previous code (for example, `0` is the index for the `'Blues'` ramp):

```
ramp = defStyle.colorRamp(defaultColorRampNames[0]) # 0 is the index for the 'Blues' ramp
```

With these premises, you may slightly edit your code in this way:

```
defStyle = QgsStyleV2().defaultStyle()
defaultColorRampNames = defStyle.colorRampNames()
ramp = defStyle.colorRamp(defaultColorRampNames[0])

for code, (color, label) in attribute_sym.items():
    sym = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    category = QgsRendererCategoryV2(code, sym, label)
    categories.append(category)

self.field = self.dockwidget.comboBox.currentText()
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2(self.field, categories)
renderer.updateColorRamp(ramp) #update the color ramp before setting the renderer
layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```